# SAS sql join tables based on function rather than variable match

Tags: sql, date

In SAS, I have data on the unique billing cycle lengths associated with individual customers, as shown below in Table A.

TABLE A

```
Cust_ID Bill_Start  Bill_End
1   1/3/12  1/29/12
1   1/29/12 2/25/12
2   1/10/12 2/6/12
2   2/6/12  2/29/12
```

I also have daily observations of a particular phenomenon throughout the entire period in Table B.

TABLE B

```
Date    Numb
1/1/12  2
1/2/12  4
1/3/12  3
1/4/12  9
1/5/12  4
1/6/12  7
1/7/12  0
1/8/12  2
1/9/12  3
1/10/12 0
1/11/12 3
1/12/12 8
1/13/12 5
1/14/12 9
1/15/12 9
1/16/12 4
1/17/12 6
1/18/12 2
1/19/12 10
1/20/12 3
1/21/12 8
1/22/12 6
1/23/12 6
1/24/12 0
1/25/12 6
1/26/12 1
1/27/12 7
1/28/12 9
1/29/12 0
1/30/12 8
1/31/12 7
2/1/12  3
2/2/12  8
2/3/12  7
2/4/12  1
2/5/12  4
2/6/12  6
2/7/12  5
2/8/12  8
2/9/12  10
2/10/12 2
2/11/12 1
2/12/12 8
2/13/12 1
2/14/12 1
2/15/12 10
2/16/12 5
2/17/12 10
2/18/12 6
2/19/12 7
2/20/12 9
2/21/12 7
2/22/12 8
2/23/12 1
2/24/12 5
2/25/12 9
2/26/12 1
2/27/12 4
2/28/12 7
2/29/12 2
```

For each customer, I need to calculate the sum of this phenomenon over the dates of the relevant billing cycle and join this sum to Table A. I also need to count the number of positive (non-zero) occurrences of this phenomenon over the relevant billing cycle and join this to Table A, as below.

```
Cust_ID Bill_Start  Bill_End    Sum Count
1   1/3/12  1/29/12 130 23
1   1/30/12 2/25/12 157 27
2   1/10/12 2/6/12  146 25
2   2/7/12  2/29/12 127 23
```

Since my customer dataset (Table A) contains millions of observations, the process needs to be efficient.

I tried this in SAS using proc sql, but it did not work. (This code refers to the actual datasets I'm working with, rather than the example datasets above.)

```
proc sql;
create table clarke.billperweather as
select a.*
select  sum(b.precip) as billtotprecip_azmet,
        count(b.precip) as billnprecipdays_azmet,
        sum(b.azmet_ET) as billtotET_azmet
from    clarke.twbill2012 a,
        clarke.azmet_daily b
where b.sasdate between a.sasstartdate and a.sasreaddate;
quit;
```

Comment: This appears to be doing an the equilivant of an inner join.  Wouldn't it need to be an outer join as not all of table a dates would exist within table b? also, could twbil2012 have a time component as well as date that may not align to the sasdate if it had a time or are we really dealing with just "dates" and no time component?  Perhaps you need  a group by... and `select a.* select sum(...)` without a subselect or comma seems improper SQL

Comment: The list in Table B is exhaustive of all dates in Table A. And there is no time component; pure dates are used. I corrected the select issue by adding a comma and tried the left join method with the group by statement as you suggested. The error message read: "Sort execution failure". I think the problem is that none of the variables listed in the group by statement exist in Table B, so sql can't group and then match. I need the function to be calculated over the appropriate date range for each observation, and then simply matched to Table A in an iterative fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Not too familar with SAS... but SQL seemed wrong without group by on 3 fields

Perhaps this assuming twbill2012 may have date ranges not found in azmet_daily

```
create table clarke.billperweather as
select  a.cust_ID, a.sasstartdate, a.sasreaddate,
        sum(coalesce(b.precip,0)) as billtotprecip_azmet,
        count(coalesce(b.precip,0)) as billnprecipdays_azmet,
        sum(coalesce(b.azmet_ET,0)) as billtotET_azmet
from    clarke.twbill2012 a 
LEFT JOIN clarke.azmet_daily b
  on b.sasdate between a.sasstartdate and a.sasreaddate
GROUP BY a.cust_ID, a.sasstartdate, a.sasreaddate
```

Assuming sasdate and sasstartdate and sasreaddate are indexed, this should be pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed to use a subquery to select the relevant dates and calculate the functions. Then, only Table A and the calculated fields were needed rather than a join statement.

```
proc sql;
create table clarke.billweather2012 as
select  a.*,
        (select sum(b.precip) from clarke.azmet_daily b where b.sasdate between a.sasstartdate and a.sasreaddate) as billtotprecip,
        (select sum(b.rain) from clarke.azmet_daily b where b.sasdate between a.sasstartdate and a.sasreaddate) as billprecipdays,
        (select sum(b.azmet_et) from clarke.azmet_daily b where b.sasdate between a.sasstartdate and a.sasreaddate) as billtotet
from clarke.billgeog2012 a
order by a.locid, a.billyear, a.billmonth;
quit;
```